# React: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

i'm trying to only render the component `<IntercomClient />` after a user clicks "Accept" on a cookie consent banner. Clicking accept changes the GlobalLayout's `intercomIsActive` state to `true` and thereby renders the IntercomClient. This is working but the warning concerns me.

How can I workaround the child/parent state change? I've been looking around but don't really understand.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { CookieBanner } from '@palmabit/react-cookie-law'

import IntercomClient from '../components/intercomClient'

const GlobalLayout = ({ location, children }) => {
   const [intercomIsActive, setIntercomIsActive] = useState(false)

   return (
   ...
      <CookieBanner
        onAccept={() => setIntercomIsActive(true)}
      />

      <IntercomClient active={intercomIsActive}/>
   ...
  )}
```

IntercomClient

```js
import React from 'react';

import Intercom from 'react-intercom'

const IntercomClient = ({ active }) => {
  return active ? <div><Intercom appID="XXXXXX" /></div> : null
}


export default IntercomClient;
```

Comment: I've tried the same with `{intercomIsActive && <IntercomClient />}` but the same warning appears

Comment: how come Layout component wraps `const [intercomIsActive, setIntercomIsActive] = useState(false)`?

Comment: @ilkeraran thanks for pointing out - i had written excerpt wrong above. Edited to reflect actual code

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const Example = () => {
  const [intercomIsActive, setIntercomIsActive] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Layout>
     ...
      <CookieBanner
        onAccept={() => setIntercomIsActive(true)}
      />

      <IntercomClient active={intercomIsActive}/>
     ...
   </Layout>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

Comment: thanks, please see my edit above, I had written excerpt wrong. My code is currently like your answer - the warning remains

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
const Example = () => {
const [intercomIsActive, setIntercomIsActive] = useState(false)

return (
  <Layout>
 ...
  <CookieBanner
    onAccept={() => setIntercomIsActive(true)}
  />
    {
         intercomIsActive &&
          <IntercomClient active={intercomIsActive}/>
       }

       ...
       </Layout>
    );
};
export default Example;
```

Comment: thanks, please see my edit above, I had written excerpt wrong. My code is currently like your answer - the warning remains

Comment: That will leave me with the same question, can ypu provide Intercom component? I belive the problem will be inside one of those as the code of your example component looks good.

Comment: index.js: 
https://github.com/nhagen/react-intercom/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the callback for `onAccept` in `CookieBanner`  as the warning points to that line. So I think it is upset with the way the state is being changed but I can't figure it out